# Cannot upload photo with refit using Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, refit

I try to Upload a photo from web MVC to API by refit but alway return 400 bad request and data send from client is null
These are my codes:

```
//Refit
[Multipart]
[Post("/api/products/{id}/uploadphoto")]
public Task<ApiResponse<bool>> UploadPhoto(int id,[AliasAs("file")]  StreamPart streamPart);

//Service
   public async Task<bool> UpdaloadPhoto2(int id, IFormFile file)
        {
            var stream = file.OpenReadStream();
            StreamPart streamPart = new StreamPart(stream, file.FileName, file.ContentType, file.Name);
            var res = await productClient.UploadPhoto(id,streamPart);
            if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return true;
            }
            var content = res.Error.Content;
            AddErrors(content);
            return false;
        }

//Comsume
   [HttpPost("{id}/uploadphoto")]
        public IActionResult UploadPhoto(int id,[FromForm] IFormFile file)
        {
           var res= productService.UploadPhoto(id,file);
           if(res!=null) return Ok();
           return BadRequest(); 
        }
```

Comment: Can you explain what these code parts do? How they are dependent on each other and where do you get 400 error in the code?

Comment: StreamPart is a wrapper class of Stream in Refit 
https://github.com/reactiveui/refit#multipart-uploads

Comment: I use Refit to call API , I try to upload a Photo , wrap it in StreamPart then send to API, but response return 400 , my validation told that "the file is required"

Answer (score 0):

The controller needs to receive an `IList` of `IFormFile`

Try

```
public IActionResult UploadPhoto(int id, IList<IFormFile> files)
```